# JFileChooser.getSelectedFile() on MacOS Sierra

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser, macos-sierra

In my current project I am using the `JFileChooser` dialog to allow users to save either one downloaded file to a specific path (like `Users/User/Documents/doc.json`) or a set of files to an existing directory (`Users/User/Documents`) where the single files would than be placed.

While the first version works just fine, the second one is a bit tricky. The actual code looks as follows:

```java
String currentSaveDirectory = (String) config.getProperties().get("lastDownloadDirectory");
fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(currentSaveDirectory));

if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    ArrayList<Pair<String,String>> processItems = (ArrayList<Pair<String,String>>) view.getList_process().getSelectedValuesList();
    String selectedDirectory = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getPath();
```

The issue occurs exactly in the last line. While I can download a set of items just fine with Windows OS or Linux, on MacOS the line

```java
fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getPath();
```

simply returns a `NullPointerException`, which is caused by the selected file being a `NULL` reference. If I instead use

```java
fileChooser.getCurrentDirectory().getPath();
```

I get exactly the path value that I need. My question is now whether one of these versions is actually flawed and should not be used (*so its basically my mistake*) or whether this is in fact a case of differing behaviour between MacOS and Windows/Linux?

Has anyone made similar experiences and could give me some feedback?

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://gist.github.com/jnizet/5516e4aab8068e89fa9e74503899faf1. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem. And post the complete stack trace of the exception it produces.

Comment: You seem to be right. Actually everything appears to be a code placement issue. While setting the current directory to the `JFileChooser` after calling it appears to be working in Windows it does not with Mac. Simply put the `setCurrentDirectory` in front of the `showSaveDialog`. Not only does that make more sense - it is also working now. I find it interesting that this behaviour just made issues on a Mac. Thank you for your help. While this issue appears to be somewhat obvious I guess I wouldn't have found it all to soon.